# Ошибки при выполнении команды MPI_Scatter Java

Tags: java, массивы, компиляция, mpi

Пытаюсь запустит следующий код -

```
import mpi.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MPI.Init(args);

        int rank = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Rank();
        int size = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Size();

        int[][] sendbuf = {
                {1, 2, 3, 4},
                {1, 10, 3, 3},
                {2, 2, 2, 2},
                {1, 1, 1, 1}
        };
        int[] recvbuf = new int[4];

        if (rank == 0) {
            MPI.COMM_WORLD.Scatter(sendbuf, 4, 4, MPI.INT, recvbuf, 4, 4, MPI.INT, 0);
            System.out.println("Rank = " + rank + " Result: " + recvbuf[0] + " " + recvbuf[1] + " " + recvbuf[2] + " " + recvbuf[3]);
        }

        MPI.Finalize();
    }
}
```

Когда выполнение доходит до команды MPI.COMM_WORLD.Scatter выходят ошибки:

```
Caused by: mpi.MPIException: mpi.MPIException: java.lang.ClassCastException: [[I cannot be cast to [I
    at mpi.Comm.send(Comm.java:435)
    at mpi.PureIntracomm.MST_Scatter(PureIntracomm.java:1096)
    at mpi.PureIntracomm.Scatter(PureIntracomm.java:1066)
    at mpi.Intracomm.Scatter(Intracomm.java:420)
    at Main.main(Main.java:24)
    ... 6 more
    Caused by: mpi.MPIException: java.lang.ClassCastException: [[I cannot be cast to [I
    at mpi.SimplePackerInt.pack(SimplePackerInt.java:87)
    at mpi.Comm.send(Comm.java:424)
    ... 10 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: [[I cannot be cast to [I
    at mpi.SimplePackerInt.pack(SimplePackerInt.java:84)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: откуда взята библиотека? на какой платформе запускаете?

Comment: вы при вызове указываете тип `MPI.INT`, а передаете массив массивов `int`.

Comment: эт так и есть MPI.INT - int;

Comment: сравните int, int[] и int[][] - видите, что это разные типы?

Comment: получается я не могу использовать двумерный массив в MPI??

Comment: вы должны соблюдать контракт. почитайте документацию.